# Firebase Auth DisplayName Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a web app that stores user's profile info into Firestore's document. I am currently storing the user displayed name under a field in Firestore. Recently, I just noticed that there is a `displayName` field under the user that I can get with

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
}
```

I am wondering if there is a possibility to query user using that `displayName` stored in auth? Similar to the Firestore query:

```
var query = userRef.where("displayed_name", "==", "xxx");
```

Comment: You can simply do a `firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName` to get said persons (who's logged in) display name

Comment: Without knowing more about what you're storing about each user, and how you're storing it, it's not possible to know what you can do.  Information in Firebase Auth is not also stored in other databases by default.  If you're using Firestore, and you want to query it for user info, you'll also have to write code to populate that data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just logged in user displayName, use the code with inline condition. Inline condition will prevent crashes.

```
const displayName = firebase.auth()?.currentUser?.displayName
```

Or you can fetch the list of users using a server because of client side isn't secure for admin managements. You can see the docs for fetching list of users. [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users)